# Send button value from android to mysql db

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

I have a question to complete my android app. First, I'll quickly explain what I'm doing.

My application is like a voting system and it will has only 2 buttons (Yes / No). Initially created a logic to when clicked a button, fill a variable with yes or no.

But I'm trying to pass the direct value of the button, instead of filling out variables. At this time, when I click the yes button, the application is exploding when you try to parse.

Can someone help me? thank you very much. Below is the code (java and xml interface)

MainActivity.java

```
package com.clubee.vote;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int loader = R.drawable.loader;
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgVotacao);
    String image_url = "http://clubee.com.br/imgs/vote_imgs/Edicao.png";
    ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
    imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);

    Button btnVotoSim = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSim);

    btnVotoSim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new InsereVoto().execute();
        }
    });
}

 class InsereVoto extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Inserindo Voto..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String tipoVoto = "sim";

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tipoVoto", tipoVoto));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_Insere_voto, "POST", params);

        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Splashscreen.class);
                startActivity(i);

                finish();
            } else {
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText tipoVoto;
private static String url_Insere_voto = "http://dev.clubee.com.br/insereVoto.php";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
```

}

And the activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fffcfffa"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bkg_app" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/infoVotacao"
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:layout_below="@id/imgLogo"
    android:text="@string/infoVotacao"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgVotacao"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/infoVotacao"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSim"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SIM"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@drawable/votebtngreen_btn_default_holo_light"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNao"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NÃO"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@drawable/votebtnred_btn_default_holo_light"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
02-14 13:16:36.995 9799-10217/com.clubee.vote E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject 
02-14 13:16:36.995 9799-10217/com.clubee.vote W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415bdd88) 
02-14 13:16:37.005 9799-10217/com.clubee.vote E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 Process: com.clubee.vote, PID: 9799 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
```

Comment: Shows your `logcat`. What error appear?

Comment: Tks for response @tomloprod

02-14 13:16:36.995   9799-10217/com.clubee.vote E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-14 13:16:36.995   9799-10217/com.clubee.vote W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415bdd88)
02-14 13:16:37.005   9799-10217/com.clubee.vote E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.clubee.vote, PID: 9799
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Comment: @tomloprod, i think that the issue is JSON Parser.

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    //EditText inputName;
    //EditText inputPrice;
    //EditText inputDesc;
    EditText tipoVoto;

but do not know how to directly pass the value of the button. 
I think my button do not have a setted value as default

Comment: Maybe this link will be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16663548/4359029

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse an XML string as if it were JSON.