# how to post request data to web services in Android?

Tags: android

I want to send some data to web services using dot net .svc web service.I have use HttpPost and BasicNameValuePair for sending some data to web service , but I'm getting error in responce string .Thanks !!.

Here is log information

```
Editable Post﹕ = ﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  <head>    <title>Request Error</title>    <style>BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}</style>  </head>  <body>    <div id="content">      <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>      <p xmlns="">The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the <a rel="help-page" href="http://103.24.4.60/classnk1/MobileService.svc/help">service help page</a> for constructing valid requests to the service.</p>    </div>  </body></html>
01-21 16:18:49.132  16744-17063/com.example.tazeen.classnkk D/@@@@ Http Post :﹕ Response org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@565746f
01-21 16:18:49.132  16744-17063/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-21 16:18:49.132  16744-17063/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-21 16:18:49.132  16744-17063/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
01-21 16:18:49.132  16744-17063/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
01-21 16:18:49.132  16744-17063/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.Edit_Post$9.doInBackground(Edit_Post.java:972)
01-21 16:18:49.132  16744-17063/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.Edit_Post$9.doInBackground(Edit_Post.java:911)
01-21 16:18:49.132  16744-17063/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
01-21 16:18:49.132  16744-17063/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-21 16:18:49.132  16744-17063/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-21 16:18:49.132  16744-17063/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-21 16:18:49.132  16744-17063/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-21 16:18:49.133  16744-17063/com.example.tazeen.classnkk W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here is code for written web service.

```
public void ActivityUpload( final String strCurrentDateTime, final String strTitle, final String replaceDescChar, final String editedHashTag)
    {

        new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>()
        {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)
            {
                HttpClient httpClient1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String strupdate_Upload = namespace + "/Upd_Post_Activity";
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(strupdate_Upload);


                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(11);
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ActionDate", strCurrentDateTime));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ActivityId", strActivityId));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserId", str_UserId));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ObjectId", strVessId));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", strTitle));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Remark", replaceDescChar));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Status", "PENDING"));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Type", strType));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("starflag", "0"));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("HashTag", editedHashTag));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Authentication_Token", str_Authentication_Token));


                //Encoding POST data
                try
                {

                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                {
                    // log exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //making POST request.
                try
                {

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient1.execute(httpPost);
                    InputStream inputStream = response .getEntity().getContent();
                    if (inputStream != null)
                        strEditableResult = Constant.convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                    else
                        strEditableResult = "Did not work!";
                    Log.e("Editable Post", " = " + strEditableResult);
                    // write response to log
                    Log.d(" @@@@ Http Post :", " Response " + response.toString());
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e)
                {
                    // Log exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Log exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                if (strEditableResult != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(strEditableResult);
                        String jsonResult = jsonObj.toString().trim();
                        Log.e("jsonResult ", " = " + jsonResult);
                        catch (JSONException je)
                         {
                            je.printStackTrace();
                         }

                         }
                return result;

            }
        }.execute();


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your parsing response JSON, as it is covered with XML tag.
Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16663548/2252016) answer.