# String cannot be converted to JSONObject exception - Android

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I'm getting a Value Database of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to J_SON Object error when I try and run the following code.I cant make any sense of other answers on here.

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

try {    

JSONObject json= new JSONObject(progress[0]);
//display response data

if (json.getString("msg")==null)
return;
if (json.getString("msg").equalsIgnoreCase("user is added")) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json.getString("msg"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 String url="http://192.168.1.100:8080/TwitterServer/login.php?email="+etEmail.getText().toString()+"&password="+etPassword.getText().toString() ;

new MyAsyncTaskgetNews().execute(url);
            }

if (json.getString("msg").equalsIgnoreCase("Pass Login")) {
JSONArray UserInfo=new JSONArray( json.getString("info"));
JSONObject UserCreintal= UserInfo.getJSONObject(0);

hideProgressDialog();
SaveSettings saveSettings= new SaveSettings(getApplicationContext());
saveSettings.SaveData(UserCreintal.getString("user_id"));
finish(); 
            }

} catch (JSONException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();

 }
    } `
```

This is the error

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
W/System.err:     at com.example.kabzjoe.bakewithme.Login$MyAsyncTaskgetNews.onProgressUpdate(Login.java:332)
W/System.err:     at com.example.kabzjoe.bakewithme.Login$MyAsyncTaskgetNews.onProgressUpdate(Login.java:295)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:681)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: where is your json result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663389/org-json-jsonexception-value-xml-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted)

Comment: This ain't no duplicate @AndyDeveloper, why would I then post it!

Comment: @Ahamed I have no json Result. I need to pick the result from my textfields and populate my MYSQL tables

Answer (score 1):

what is progress[0]?
String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: The declaration starts from the method parentheses  `protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

            try {`  .....

Comment: @Jacky.Lee add this line inside the try block for debug and check it Log.e("progress", ""+progress[0]); what response you were getting

Comment: @Jacky.Lee adding that line of code doesn't help at all

Comment: @Jacky.Lee The log points to the line code where the "progress[0]" is declared line 5 and 6 in the log i posted

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your back, you should add this ins your php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

With the header your response will be only the json and you could parse it